# Set Color of Chart lines and markers according to the color of other lines and markers in vba

Tags: excel, vba, charts, colors

I am trying to set the color of even lines and markers according to the color of odd lines and colors.

Let's say, my table looks like this (speed1, performance1, speed2, performance2,.....)
When I plot a line chart It just gives every line a different color. In my case I want to give every two columns (speed and performance) a single color. So, for that I try every time to take the color of a line and the color of its markers, and then assign these colors to the following line (color of odd columns to even columns).

This is my code:

```
Sub ChangeColors()

 Dim cht As Chart
 Dim ser As Series

 Set cht = ActiveChart
For i = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
 If (i Mod 2) = 0 Then
 Set dst = cht.SeriesCollection(i)
 Set src = cht.SeriesCollection(i - 1)
 dst.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
 dst.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
 dst.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = src.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
 dst.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = src.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
 End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The problem is that at the end all the even lines become black. However, when I try to pick a RGB color (for instance, RGB(255, 0, 0)) an assign it to the even lines they all become red, so it works.

**UPDATE:**
When I use a MsgBox to print the value of src.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB and src.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB I get 16777215 and 0 respectively for all lines. So I don't understand why these values and why they are the same for all lines ?

Does anyone know what is the problem with my code ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Should this line:

```
dst.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = src.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
```

instead be:

```
dst.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = src.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
```

Comment: Yes I have also tried with it but it still gives a black color, so it doesn't work. This is pretty bizarre! I don't know what to do, I have seen somewhere in the internet that this a bug in vba but I still wait for a way to do this ! Thanks!

Comment: When I use a MsgBox to print the value of src.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB and src.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB I get 16777215 and 0 respectively, which is non understandable !